Kaobook and cleveref: referencing exercises
Referencing with \cref using the kaobook class (and kaorefs package) works with most defined theorem-like environments, except, mysteriously, with exercises:
\documentclass{kaobook}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{kaotheorems}
\usepackage{kaorefs}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\begin{proposition} \label{prop:one}
  $a=b$.
\end{proposition}

\begin{exercise} \label{ex:two}
  Show that $c=d$.
\end{exercise}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm:three}
  $x\ne y$.
\end{theorem}

\Cref{prop:one}.

\Cref{ex:two}.

\Cref{thm:three}.

\end{document}

It gives:

